SonarQube 10.4.1 upgraded and I am using Java 11. How to set up my pipelines?

Project's specific JDK
In some situations, you might have to analyze a project built with a different version of Java than the one executing the analysis. The most common case is to run the analysis with Java 17, while the project itself uses Java 11 or before for its build.
If this is your case, you will need to set the sonar.java.jdkHome property manually to point the appropriate JDK (see below). By doing this you will specify which JDK classes the analyzer must refer to during the analysis. Not setting this property, while it would have been required, usually leads to inconsistent or even impossible to fix issues being reported, especially in relation with native JDK classes.
When setting sonar.java.jdkHome, you need to provide the path to the JDK directory used by the project being analyzed, if different from the Java runtime executing the analysis. For example, for a Java 11 project, by setting it as follows: sonar.java.jdkHome=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk11.0.22/
# Here maven uses the default version of Java on the system but we specify that we want to analyze a Java 11 project.
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar \
  # other analysis parameters
  -Dsonar.java.jdkHome=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk11.0.22/
  # other analysis parameters


As per above documentation, how to update my pipeline that two configurations?
I am using Azure-DevOps. Below is My Pipeline yaml.
 - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
    inputs:
      artifactsFeeds: 'MyApp'
  
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'maven | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/pom.xml'
      restoreKeys: |
        maven | "$(Agent.OS)"
        maven
      path: $(mavenCacheFolder)
    displayName: Cache Maven local repo

  - ${{ if eq(parameters.sonarEnable, 'true') }}:
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.sonarCacheEnable, 'true') }}: 
      - task: Cache@2
        inputs:
          key: 'sonar | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/pom.xml'
          restoreKeys: |
            sonar | "$(Agent.OS)"
            sonar
          path: "/home/vsts/.sonar/cache"
        displayName: Sonar cache
        
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.sonarEnable, 'true') }}:
    - task: SonarQubePrepare@6
      inputs:
        SonarQube: ${{ parameters.sonarQubeEndpoint }}
        scannerMode: 'Other'
        extraProperties: |
          sonar.projectKey=${{ parameters.sonarProjectKey }}
          sonar.host.url=$(sonarHostURL)
          sonar.login=${{ parameters.sonarLogin }}
          sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=${{ parameters.sonarCoverageJacocoXmlReportPaths }}
          sonar.exclusions= ${{ parameters.sonarExclusions }}

  - task: Maven@3
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
      goals: ${{ parameters.mavenGoal }}
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
      mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
      mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m $(mavenOpts)'
      mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
      effectivePomSkip: false
      sonarQubeRunAnalysis: ${{ parameters.sonarEnable }}
      sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'
      checkStyleRunAnalysis: true
      pmdRunAnalysis: true

  - ${{ if eq(parameters.sonarEnable, 'true') }}:
    - task: SonarQubePublish@6
      inputs:
        pollingTimeoutSec: '600'
    - task: sonar-buildbreaker@8
      inputs:
        SonarQube: ${{ parameters.sonarQubeEndpoint }}


The document mentions that this option can be added to your sonar.properties configuration.
So, you can add the sonar.java.jdkHome property to the SonarQubePrepare@6 task in your Azure DevOps pipeline YAML. Remember to replace /usr/lib/jvm/jdk11.0.22/ with the actual path to your JDK 11 installation. If the JDK is not installed on the agent, you might need to install it before running the analysis.
    - task: SonarQubePrepare@6
      inputs:
        SonarQube: ${{ parameters.sonarQubeEndpoint }}
        scannerMode: 'Other'
        extraProperties: |
          sonar.projectKey=${{ parameters.sonarProjectKey }}
          sonar.host.url=$(sonarHostURL)
          sonar.login=${{ parameters.sonarLogin }}
          sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=${{ parameters.sonarCoverageJacocoXmlReportPaths }}
          sonar.exclusions= ${{ parameters.sonarExclusions }}
          sonar.java.jdkHome=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk11.0.22/     # Add this line


My pipeline got success after I updated my maven task into two parts
Maven@4 disable sonar and run jdk with 1.11
Maven@4 enables sonar and goals: 'sonar:sonar'
options: '-Dsonar.java.jdkHome=1.17'
Jdkversion : 1.17

Hi @brucewayne, glad to hear that your pipeline got success. Can you please add an answer and share your detailed steps in the answer in case anyone else meet the same issues in the future? Thanks!

I have updated my Maven task like below then my build was successful:
- task: Maven@4
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: ${{ parameters.mavenGoal }}
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m $(mavenOpts)'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'
    checkStyleRunAnalysis: true
    pmdRunAnalysis: true

- task: Maven@4
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'sonar:sonar'
    options: '-Dsonar.java.jdkHome=1.17'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m $(mavenOpts)'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: ${{ parameters.sonarEnable }}
    sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'
    checkStyleRunAnalysis: true
    pmdRunAnalysis: true
   displayName: Sonar Analysis


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
